# Navbar dropdown needs bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets requires to work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, twitter-bootstrap-4

I use the [bootstrap gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) installed (alpha-v6) in a rails 5 app. I have a dropdown in my navbar which implemented exactly as the example in the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav).

But it is currently only working either in production or in development, depending on what I require in my application.js:

Works in development:

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

works in production:

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I know the documentation says you should not require both `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-sprockets`. But so far I can not find another way to make it work in production.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe also notable: just using ```bootstrap``` instead of ```bootstrap-sprockets``` does not work at all in development.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly recommend using the `bootstrap-sass` gem so you can take advantage of bootstrap's sass variables, classes, mixins, etc. It's also a little easier to integrate with your rails apps in my opinion, and if you want to use it the same way as your previous bootstrap gem then you can do that too. My answer banks on you using the `bootstrap-sass` gem.

According the [bootstrap gem documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/README.md), you should not include both bootstrap and bootstrap sprockets.

According to the docs:

> bootstrap-sprockets provides individual Bootstrap Javascript files (alert.js or dropdown.js, for example), while bootstrap provides a concatenated file containing all Bootstrap Javascripts.

So to properly include bootstrap's JavaScript functionality:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks 
//= require_tree
```

Also, this assumes you're using the gem `bootstrap-sass`

Comment: I know about not using bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets together, as I have mentioned in my question. And I am not using bootstrap-saas. I am using the new bootstrap gem, see the link to the gem in my question.

Comment: See the second line in the readme of the bootstrap-saas gem: I am using bootstrap 4 and I am using the correct gem for that. bootstrap-saas will not support bootstrap 4.

Comment: Gotcha. Anyhow, in your gemfile.lock, what is your version of sprockets-rails?

Comment: sprockets-rails is on 3.2.0

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try requiring jquery_ujs immediately after jquery and before anything else

Comment: tried that already, as I said, I have tried lots of sequences

Answer (score 0):

I have it currently working by explicitly calling the dropdown function every time turbolinks reloads the page.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
})
```

But I should not have to do this so I would really like to have a real answer to the problem.